# Google Translate API error when restricting API access [Android]

Tags: android, api, google-cloud-platform, android-volley, google-translate

I've started using the Google Translate API and the problem is the following:
If APi is unrestricted, obviously, I can use it (via REST - POST), but if I restrict the usage of the API to my android app, using, as the documentation says, my package name and my keystore SHA1... but then I get a `com.android.volley.AuthFailureError`

```
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:165)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

and I cannot access the API.

Any idea of what the hell is going on? Thank you.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Haven't found a solution yet. This used to work as far as I can tell. The code I'm working on isn't mine but I'm pretty certain it did work and now I have to fix it :S

Comment: Glad to hear that I'm not alone! I'm using a simple volley request, that I've used many times with no problem with other APIs. This is weird, as it is damn Google!

I hope someone can help us :(